# Show that mapping from polynomial to a real number is a linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

> Denote by $$\Pi_{2}\left([0,1]\right) = \{t \mapsto c_0 + c_{1}t + c_{2}t^2 \ :\ c_k \in \mathbb{R}\ \text{and}\ t\in [0,1] \}$$
>
> the set of polynomials of at most degree 2 with real coefficients defined over $[0,1]$. Equipped with pointwise addition and multiplication by scarlars this set and operations defines a linear space over $\mathbb {R}$.

1. show that $\Pi_{2}\left([0,1]\right) \overset{T}{\to} \mathbb {R}$ defined by $p \mapsto T(p) = p(1) - p(0)$ is a linear mapping.

To show its a linear mapping we need to prove: $$1.\ f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$  $$2.\ f(\lambda(x)) = \lambda(x).$$

$1.$ Let $p,q$ be elements of the 2-degree polynomial from the question such that $p(t) = p_o + p_1x + p_2x^2 $and $q(t) = q_o + q_1x + q_2x^2.$

$T(p+q) = T([p_o + p_1x + p_2x^2] + [q_o + q_1x + q_2x^2]) = (p(1) + q(1)) - (p(0)+ q(0)) =[p(1) -p(0)] + [q(1)-q(0)] = T(p) + T(q)$

$2$ Let $\lambda$ be a scalar that is an element of the set of real numbers and p be an element of the 2-degree polynomial such that $ p(t) = p_o + p_1x + p_2x^2.$

$T(λp) = T(λp_o + λp_1x + p_2x^2) = λp(1) - λp(0) = λ(p(1) - p(0)) = λT(p) $ as required.

Would this be correct?

Comment: It's fine, but you don't need to write down the express form of each polynomial.

Comment: welcome to MSE. please try avoid using in embed pictures, but instead try using MathJax

Comment: Sure, but whats wrong with using embed pictures? It saves me time and i have alot of studying to do @Jneven

Comment: other users won't be able to find the question if they are looking for it. this is a community. asking questions is a big part of it. but the information should be as available as possible.

Comment: @Jneven Well these questions are exam questions from my university and are not available to the public so most people wouldn't be able to find them anyway.

Comment: please fix the rest of the question. (instead of λ you should use \lambda, for example.

Comment: so you shouldn't be uploading it in here.

Comment: Randy, this site is not *for you*, it's for *everyone*. Using text and MathJax instead of pictures improves the overall interface of the site, the readability for people who use screen readers, and search results both on the site and from Google when people are looking for related topics and questions. Remember that the questions you ask are likely to be similar to questions that other people have elsewhere. Not everything is confined around your exams.

Comment: Seen the changes, much better.